# Using Python3 to modify javascript efficiently

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

Is there any *more* efficient method of editing javascript using python like with native function like push to edit the text? I currently do this:

```py
output += f"var {newArraySTR()} = ['templateARRAY']"
for i in functions:
  output.replace("'templateARRAY'",f"'{i}','tepmlateARRAY'")
```

And it's proven much harder to cleanly modify the javascript.

Comment: Slightly tangential, but if you have a requirement to use code to modify other code, you're likely missing a much, *much* easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do (likely an XY problem). Can you elaborate a bit more on your broader use case for this? Why not just generate JSON-formatted data and consume it directly in your JavaScript, since it's easily parse-able in both languages out of the box, instead of directly modifying something more difficult-to-parse like raw JS code?

Comment: Does "efficient" here mean "easier to use" or does it mean "more performant"?

Comment: I'm guessing that this code is just an idea, if it is not, I strongly suspect it is not doing what you hope it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific example, I would not rebuild the array that way. I would use json.dumps to just give me something more js friendly.

I would start with something like:

```
import json

functions = ["one", "two"]
variable_name = "foo"
variable_value = json.dumps(functions)

js_output = f'''
var {variable_name} = {variable_value};
{variable_name}.forEach(item => {{
    console.log(item);
}});
'''

print(js_output)
```

Giving:

```js
var foo = ["one", "two"];
foo.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
});
```

I might also look into a more formal template facility like jinja if this did not work for you.